# MSTest comparing list of Mock.Of<IFoo> to List of Foo

Tags: c#, collections, moq, mstest

What is the right way to compare a list of Moq Foo vs List of Expected

I believe the answer to this is going to be something to do with the Moq objects but i have tried a few variations of Assert with the same general results.

```
        var moq = new List<IFoo>
        {
            Mock.Of<IFoo>(f => f.Description == "thing one" && f.Price == 0m),
            Mock.Of<IFoo>(f => f.Description == "thing two" && f.Price == 0m),
            Mock.Of<IFoo>(f => f.Description == "thing three" && f.Price == 0m),
        };

        var concrete = new List<IFoo>
        {
            new Foo{ Description = "thing one", Price = 0m},
            new Foo{ Description = "thing two", Price = 0m },
            new Foo{ Description = "thing three", Price = 0m },
        };


        //both fail
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(moq, concrete);
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(moq, concrete);
    }
```

Also noteworthy, I am overriding `public override bool Equals(object obj)`

this is a failing test that represents a similar scenario i am running into. I believe that if this passes then so will the issue i am trying to solve.

I have looked around SO as well as the Google and am likely just not searching with the correct wording.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

based on @Nkosi comment and some additional digging
There is **NO NEED** to moq the expected list. just downcast the list to IFoo and pre-fill with new Foo of expected. you will likely need to override the `Equals` method on your concrete instance of `IFoo`

```
    var moq = new List<IFoo>
    {
        new Foo{ Description = "thing one", Price = 0m},
        new Foo{ Description = "thing two", Price = 0m },
        new Foo{ Description = "thing three", Price = 0m },
    };
```

with this approach both will pass

```
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual
 CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent
```

noteworthy, if i left the expected list as a moq list and swapped the asserts around the following would happen

```
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(concrete, moq);//pass
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(concrete, moq);//fail
```

when asserting AreEqual the is equal method is called for the expected object
when asserting AreEquivalent the equal method is called for both the moq and the returned list.

Overall I am not sure why i was moqing the expected list, was not needed in this case.

Comment: You came to the correct conclusion. Good work and glad you figured it out.